# [Table 'db_name.wp_termmeta' doesn't exist]

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datatables

> [Table 'db_name.wp_termmeta' doesn't exist]

```
SELECT term_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_termmeta WHERE term_id IN (2,5,3,4,6,1) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

When I am updating my WordPress from 4.4 version to 4.9 version I am getting this error.The table doesn't exist if I am making the table than it give this error

> 1813 - Tablespace for table '`db_name`.`wp_termmeta`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT."

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop **db_name.wp_termmeta** refresh and then import. It will fix the issue.

Comment: But wouldn't that bring them back to the first part of the original question - where the WP updater is reporting the table doesn't exist?

Comment: yes.I am trying to drop but,it says unknown table  "db_name.wp_termmeta"

Comment: if you have PhpMyAdmin access directly go there and try to find the table.

Comment: the table does'nt exits

Comment: when I am creating the table it says  #1813 - Tablespace for table '`qamarcon_qc`.`wp_termmeta`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.